# Intellij idea libgdx java lambda expressions are not supported in source

Tags: java, intellij-idea, lambda, libgdx

Answers at stackoverflow:

1) Solution: "In File Menu → Project Structure → Project, change Project Language Level to 8.0 - Lambdas, type annotations etc" is not working.

2) Also: "change source code Language Level also on the Source tab (Modules part)" not working too.

Still the same error.

After program restart 1) and 2) resets to default and its not 1.8.

3) "add something in POM file" - i have no any POM file.

So what should i do for using lambda in intellij idea? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Check if SDK is pointed to JAVA 8 and above

[image]

Comment: i started the program to check, and sdk was set to 1.8 already. But as i said module is 7 version and setting it in 8 doesn't help.